# Reverting GIT directories to previous ones in RStudio

Tags: r, git, rstudio, git-revert

I am using Rstudio to build an R package with version control being handled by GIT. There was a mistake and several files were overwritten and I would like to be able to revert back to a previous version in the commit timeline.

Can I use the SHA number to revert back to that version? Also, I am using RStudio so is there an easy way to do that in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING THIS WILL DELETE EVERYTHING YOU HAVE DONE SINCE THE COMMIT**

`git reset --hard SHA-NUMBER`

Comment: This did not change the files on Git, but only on my local machine.

Comment: did you push the changes?

`git add .`
`git commit -m 'blew everything up'`
`git push`

Comment: So I just need to issue those three commands? Also, the changes were actually that the file names changed.  For example, before I had a file like example.1.R and now the file is example1.R.  So would both files appear after the push since they have different names?

Comment: Or would I have to delete all the files with different names? And if so what is the git command for that?

Comment: git will revert everything to **EXACTLY** as it was before you committed.

Comment: it didn't work, I got this message: ` ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)` 
`error: failed to push some refs to 'http://bp/bp.git'`
`hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`
`hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`
`hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`